# Key Error while subsetting Timeseries data using index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, subset

I have the following `Timeseries` data.

```
price_per_year.head()
            price
      date  
2013-01-02  20.08
2013-01-03  19.78
2013-01-04  19.86
2013-01-07  19.40
2013-01-08  19.66

price_per_year.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 782 entries, 2013-01-02 to 2015-12-31
Data columns (total 1 columns):
price    756 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 12.2 KB
```

I am trying to extract data for 3 years using the below code. Why is that I am getting `KeyError: '2014'`, when the data as shown below clearly contains year '2014'. Appreciate any inputs.

```
price_per_year['2014'].head()
            price
      date  
2014-01-01  NaN
2014-01-02  39.59
2014-01-03  40.12
2014-01-06  39.93
2014-01-07  40.92

prices = pd.DataFrame()
for year in ['2013', '2014', '2015']:
    price_per_year = price_per_year.loc[year, ['price']].reset_index(drop=True)
    price_per_year.rename(columns={'price': year}, inplace=True)
    prices = pd.concat([prices, price_per_year], axis=1)

KeyError: '2014'
```

The code line `price_per_year.loc['2014', ['price']]`, when used independently outside `for loop`, works fine, while `price_per_year['price'][year]` when used in the `for loop` doesn't work.

```
for year in ['2013', '2014', '2015']:
    price_per_year = price_per_year['price'][year].reset_index(drop=True)

KeyError: 'price'
```

Both the code lines `price_per_year.loc[price_per_year.index.year == 2014, ['price']]` when used independently outside `for loop` and `price_per_year.loc[price_per_year.index.year == year, ['price']]` used inside the `for loop` are giving errors.

```
for year in ['2013', '2014', '2015']:
    price_per_year.loc[price_per_year.index.year == '2014', ['price']].reset_index(drop=True)

TypeError: Cannot convert input [False] of type <class 'bool'> to Timestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem in your first code is used [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing), here is used [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
prices = pd.DataFrame()
for year in ['2013', '2014', '2015']:
    s = price_per_year['price'][year].reset_index(drop=True).rename(year)
    prices = pd.concat([prices, s], axis=1)
print (prices)
    2013   2014   2015
0  20.08  19.86  19.66
1  19.78  19.40  19.66
```

Another better solution with reshape:

```
print (df)
            price
date             
2013-01-02  20.08
2013-01-03  19.78
2014-01-02  19.86
2014-01-03  19.40
2015-01-02  19.66
2015-01-03  19.66

y = df.index.year
df = df.set_index([df.groupby(y).cumcount(), y])['price'].unstack()
print (df)
date   2013   2014   2015
0     20.08  19.86  19.66
1     19.78  19.40  19.66
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs. Whiele the reshaping solution suggested by you indeed does work, the options suggested to my code do encounter errors. I have updated the same in the original question. Kindly have a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Srinivas - Problem is overwriten variable  `price_per_year`, so changed it to `s` and also is used `rename`, edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Got it. It works. It works with even df.loc[year, ['price']].reset_index(drop=True).